# Unable to see "Single Page Application" Project template under "Select Template" (VS 2012)

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I am using Visual Studio 2012 Premium. I want to develop an ASP.net MVC 4 based SPA (Single Page Application). In the tutorials that I have seen in the internet, I have seen the usage of "Single Page Application" Project template in Visual Studio. In my version of Visual Studio, I do not see "Single Page Application" template appearing under "Select a template" dialog box, after I choose "ASP.net MVC 4 Web Application" from the new project. I know that I can download template packages from Nuget , but my question is, which template I need to install to get "Single Page Application" project template.

Answer (score 0):

I ran the Update 4 for Visual Studio Premium 2012. I can now see "Single Page Application" in the "Select a template" dialogue box.